# lua compile require errors

Tags: lua, compiler-errors

I get tons of errors after I compile a lua file into a stand-alone program (i.e. exe) with srlua.

Always anything in the "require()" it cannot find later and the program will simply not run.

Is there a way to solve this and so the program will run properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `require`, the default methods scan directories based on the location of `lua.exe`. srLua seems to not handle dependencies. Perhaps you should use [Lua Built-In Program](http://sourceforge.net/projects/l-bia/) instead. The project seems to be abandoned, but it did have a release in 2010, so it's mostly recent.

Comment: This doesn't work though. And its not a compiler either.
It gives the same errors. Isn't there a way to properly set the path than or whatever. To get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good results from using [Squish](http://matthewwild.co.uk/projects/squish/home) recently to collect a bunch of Lua modules and several related scripts together so that they could be packaged in a single exe along with their host app.

I did have to make some tweaks to build and use it in Windows, but they were all obvious extensions or translations of the Unix-centric existing source kit. Squish itself is written in pure Lua, and building it applies squish to itself to generate a single self-contained script file for use with the normal Lua interpreter.

In addition to handling dependent modules, it can also compile and/or compress the code for even smaller output.

If you are working with the stock Lua interpreter, then using Squish to get a single file and srlua to package it with the interpreter is probably a good combination.